# ssh not working when changing static ip address in dhcpcd.conf (raspberry pi)

Tags: raspberry-pi, ip-address

This is probably a basic question for anyone versed in networks, but very esoteric for me.
I have two raspberry pi 4 (connected in a local network throught a fast switch (netgear fs108). If i read the ip adresses given by default to the raspberries (via hostname -I) i obtain a address that allows me to do ssh betwen the raspberries without any problem (the degault adresses are the same provided that i always connect the raspberries to the same switch ports), but i would like to asign different ip addresses. Following several tutorials, i modify the dhcpcd.conf by adding the lines

interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.5.11/24. #192.168.5.12/24 in the second raspberry

after reboting, if i verify the new up address
hostname -I
i obtain the assigned address, but when i try to connect via ssh, with:
ssh pi@192.168.5.11
the terminal does nothing (not asking password, neither failing)

In some tutorials, i see that also the fields
static routers, and static domain_name_servers are added to the dhcpcd file, but i do not know what they are, and obviously adding the sme numbers that i see in tutorials (just to try) makes that event the
hostname -I
command does not give the address anymore.

Are those two fiels necessary, and if yes, how can Iknow which values I sould give? there is nothing written in my switch.
follwowing on this, if i change the switch and use a 'proper' router, i would need to change those values?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you been able to `ssh` into the rpi sucessfully? that is before trying to update to a static ip.

Comment: Hi, yes. If i use the ip addresses assigned by defaut (just read them using hostname -I without modifying the dhcpcd file) i have no problem at all in connecting them sending files, etc. or even connecting from a macpro to both of them in ssh or vnc.